# Welche Wörter werden in Titeln (von Büchern usw) großgeschrieben?

Tags: capitalization

Es wundert mich, dass ich online keine Dokumente zu dieser Frage finden kann. Eine Google-Suche nach "[Großbuchstaben in Titeln](https://www.google.com/search?q=Gro%C3%9Fbuchstaben+in+Titeln)" ergibt [meistens](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gro%C3%9Fschreibung#Gro%C3%9Fschreibung_in_%C3%9Cberschriften_und_Werktiteln) [Informationen](https://capitalizemytitle.com/de/) zur Großschreibung von **englischen** Titeln. Im Englischen muss man bei Titeln jedes Wort großschreiben außer Präpositionen, Konjunktionen und Artikel.

Wenn man sich nach den Titeln von Wikipedia-Artikeln richtet, sollen im Deutschen bei Titeln nur das erste Wort und natürlich alle Nomen großgeschrieben werden (*[Eine kleine Nachtmusik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eine_kleine_Nachtmusik)*, *[Der dritte Mann](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_dritte_Mann)*). Ist die Regel wirklich so? Oder gibt es überhaupt eine Regel?

Comment: Das ist bei Titeln genauso wie bei allen anderen Texten, deswegen braucht es dafür keine gesonderten Regeln.

Comment: Da Buchtitel Instrumente des Marketings sind, macht jeder, was er will; glücklicherweise die Meisten etwas Vernünftiges. Ich habe auch Buchtitel, die DURCHGÄNGIG GROSS geschrieben sind, andere schreiben alles, auch ihre titel klein.

Comment: Der Artikel der englischen [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case) definiert: "**Title case** or **headline case** is a style of capitalization used for rendering the titles of published works or works of art in English." Es gibt auch keine Fassung des Artikels in einer anderen Sprache der Wikipedia.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ja, man schreibt das erste Wort groß und der Rest ergibt sich automatisch aus der deutschen Rechtschreibung. Das Großschreiben von Wörtern, die keine Nomen sind, würde sofort als falsch auffallen.

„Kapitalisierung“ bedeutet übrigens etwas ganz anderes als „capitalisation“ im Englischen und ist ein wirtschaftlicher Begriff im Zusammenhang mit Kapital: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kapitalisierung.

Comment: So ein peinlicher Fehler... zur Info, ich habe das Wort "Kapitalisierung" jetzt von der Frage entfernt. Danke für die Antwort!

Answer (score 4):

Im Deutschen entspricht die Groß- und Kleinschreibung von Wörtern in Titeln und Überschriften der Groß- und Kleinschreibung von Wörtern in Sätzen.